# Дешифратор с "морзянки" на андроид

Tags: java, android

Это мое первое приложение на андроид и не совсем понимаю как должно все работать.

В общем, не понимаю в чем проблема. Вылетает приложение. Лог и код предоставил ниже.

Лог:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.shtraikher.stalmorzyanka, PID: 2049
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.shtraikher.stalmorzyanka/com.shtraikher.stalmorzyanka.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Window$Callback android.view.Window.getCallback()' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2882)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3087)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1817)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6724)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:495)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Window$Callback android.view.Window.getCallback()' on a null object reference
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:249)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:182)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:520)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.findViewById(AppCompatActivity.java:191)
    at com.shtraikher.stalmorzyanka.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:22)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
    at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(AppComponentFactory.java:69)
    at android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(CoreComponentFactory.java:43)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1215)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2870)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3087) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1817) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6724) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:495) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Код:

```
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.Arrays;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
}

TextView morzeInp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.inputArea);
TextView morzeOut = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.outputArea);
Button point = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pointBtn);
Button dash = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dashBtn);
String strMorzeInp = "";

void pointOnClick(View v) {
    strMorzeInp += ".";
    morzeInp.setText(strMorzeInp);
}

void dashOnClick(View v) {
    strMorzeInp += "-";
    morzeInp.setText(strMorzeInp);
}

void clearAll(View v) {
    strMorzeInp = "";
    morzeInp.setText(strMorzeInp);
}

void backspace(View v) {
    strMorzeInp.charAt(strMorzeInp.length() - 1);
    morzeInp.setText(strMorzeInp);
}

void spaceClick(View v) {
    strMorzeInp += " ";
    morzeInp.setText(strMorzeInp);
}

void getResult(View v) {
    String[] words = new String[]  {"A", "Б", "В", "Г",
                                    "Д", "Е", "Ж", "З",
                                    "И", "Й", "К", "Л",
                                    "М", "Н", "О", "П",
                                    "Р", "С", "Т", "У",
                                    "Ф", "Х", "Ц", "Ч",
                                    "Ш", "Щ", "Ъ", "Ы",
                                    "Ь", "Э", "Ю", "Я"};

    String[] morze = new String[]  {".-", "-...", ".--", "--.",
                                    "-..", ".", "...-", "--..",
                                    "..", ".---", "-.-", ".-..",
                                    "--", "-.", "---", ".--.",
                                    ".-.", "...", "-", "..-",
                                    "..-.", "....", "-.-.","---.",
                                    "----", "--.-", ".--.-.", "-.--",
                                    "-..-", "..-..", "..--", ".-.-"};

    String[] split = strMorzeInp.split(" ");
    String output = "";
    int index;
    for (String s:split) {
        index = Arrays.asList(morze).indexOf(s);
        output += words[index] + " ";
    }
    morzeOut.setText(output);
}
}
```

Comment: ну, NPE говорит само за себя. Проект даже не охото качать, если честно

Comment: ну, хотя бы есть куда копать. И на этом спасибо.

Comment: Не увлекайтесь ссылками - не каждый захочет по ним переходить и тем более что-то качать. Логи добавляйте прямо в вопрос и код, на который указывает ошибка тоже (не весь проект, естественно).

Comment: все исправил!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Инициализация полей происходит при создании экземпляра класса, а метод `onCreate` выполняется позже.
Метод `findViewById` не может работать пока активность не привязана к окну и найти нужный вью-элемент можно только после того как он создан и добавлен в окно. То есть в нашем случае после вызова `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`
Ваш код должен быть изменён с учётом вышесказанного:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView morzeInp;
    TextView morzeOut;
    Button point;
    Button dash;
    String strMorzeInp = "";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

        // находим наши вью здесь
        morzeInp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.inputArea);
        morzeOut = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.outputArea);
        point = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pointBtn);
        dash = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dashBtn);
    }
.......
```